# Charset unable to read € (Euro Symbol) from a dsv file in java

Tags: java, character-encoding

Below code does not work while reading a Euro symbol from a dsv file.

```
CSVReader csvReader = new CSVReaderBuilder(Files.newBufferedReader(sourceFile, Charset.forName("ISO-8859-9"))).withCSVParser(csvParser).build();
```

Is the `Charset` used incorrect in the above line ?

Tried `ISO-8859-1` & `ISO-8859-15` as well, but no luck.

Comment: We don't magically know which charset the file is in. You could check the byte(s) value of the euro symbol in the file and try to figure out the encoding.

Comment: You say "does not work". Does it throw an exception? Does some later program logic behave strangely? Does some output in some console look different than expected? Please give us more details. And please open the file in Notepad++, select the correct encoding so you see the Euro symbol displayed correctly there, and tell us the encoding from Notepad++'s status line.

Answer (score 2):

Do not guess. You need to find out which encoding is actually used by your CSV file.
So, start your favorite hex-editor or -viewer and look for the `€` characters.

- In [`ISO-8859-15`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-15) the `€` character is represented by hexadecimal `A4` (1 byte)
- In [`ISO-8859-1`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-1) the `€` character is not representable
- In [`ISO-8859-9`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8859-9) the `€` character is not representable
- In [`UTF-8`](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTF-8) the `€` character is represented by hexadecimal `E2 82 AC` (3 bytes)
- In [`windows-1252`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252) the `€` character is represented by hexadecimal `80` (1 byte)
- ...

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thank You for your response. It is represented by 1 byte hence tried with ISO-8859-15...but fails to read the Euro symbol

Comment: @MelbaMartis And by which byte exactly? Then it is yet another encoding. May be another one of the `ISO-8859` family, since all these are 1-byte-encodings.

Comment: Windows-1252 most likely then. A perfect answer with concrete values, and hinting at a hex editor. NotePad++ / JEdit or such can play with different charsets.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to try to read with character set `UTF-8` Some of the encodings in UTF-8 are one byte codes. That might help. Also There is a utility that may help you very much with diagnostics of your problem. There is an Open Source java library (written by me) called MgntUtils that has the utility that converts any String to unicode sequence and vise-versa. All you will have to do is:

```
String codes = StringUnicodeEncoderDecoder.encodeStringToUnicodeSequence("Hello world");
```

And it will return String `"\u0048\u0065\u006c\u006c\u006f\u0020\u0057\u006f\u0072\u006c\u0064"`

The same would work for any String in any language including special characters. Here is the link to the article [Open Source Java library with stack trace filtering, Silent String parsing Unicode converter and Version comparison](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/open-source-java-library-some-useful-utilities-michael-gantman/) that explains about the library and where to get it (available both on [Maven central](https://search.maven.org/#artifactdetails%7Ccom.github.michaelgantman%7CMgntUtils%7C1.5.0.2%7Cjar) and [github](https://github.com/michaelgantman/Mgnt). In the article search for paragraph: **"String Unicode converter"**.

So when you read your String convert it and see what comes up. Note that unicide for Euro symbol is \u20AC